# How do I make it so that an image scales up while scrolling but once it reaches a certain size the page scrolls down?

Tags: html, jquery, css, transform, scale

Essentially I really want to get this effect (http://ussr.obys.agency/1922-1930/) scroll down to the section titled GOSPROM. This website does the same thing (https://www.reformcollective.com/) I want to have it scale up until the photo in the foreground disappears and then the webpage starts scrolling down. I'm a very novice coder, mostly have been using css html and javascript (mostly jquery), any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Look into a JavaScript library for scrolling animations/triggers like https://scrollmagic.io/

Comment: This is super helpful thank you!